# Get Name of Computer Cross-platform?

Tags: osx

I'm creating a login message for my computer inside of `/etc/bashrc` and would like to greet them to the computer with the computer's name showing.

Here's my code:

```
# (system stuff here)
echo "Welcome, $(whoami)."
```

When I use `login` on any user, it gives me what I'd expect: `Welcome, avgjoe` for example.

However, I'd like to make it output `Welcome, avgjoe, to Tower of Nix` - my computer's name has been set (through System Preferences) to "Tower of Nix" already.

So, without hard-coding it in there (i.e. `echo "Welcome, $(whoami), to Tower of Nix."`), how can I get the name of my computer?

I've already tried `hostname`, but that outputs `192.168.2.13`.

Turns out, `scutil --get ComputerName` does exactly what I want (outputs `Tower of Nix`), but when I looked at the man page for `scutil`, it stated:

> #### HISTORY
>
> The `scutil` command appeared in the Mac OS X Public Beta.

So it probably won't work on all operating systems such as Linux, *BSD, etc.

My question: **How can I get the name of the computer on any** (or nearly any) **derivative of UNIX?**

Comment: Your behaviour of `hostname` sounds more like `hostname -i` to me. For completeness' sake, can you try `hostname -a` (show alias name) and `hostname -s` (show short host name)?

Comment: Can you do an `alias | grep hostname` on your system?  Because AFAIK `hostname` is pretty universal across OSes (*nix, NetWare, Windows, ...)

Comment: Updated to obviously explain the output of `hostname`: `192.168.2.13`

Comment: The Mac is the only Unix-like system I know of that lets you store and retrieve a name totally distinct from the computer's IP hostname. It's probably best to special-case it, maybe `$(scutil --get ComputerName 2>/dev/null || hostname)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS X is one of the few Unix-like systems that lets you store and retrieve a name totally distinct from the computer's IP hostname. It's probably best to special-case the call to `scutil`; if that fails, fall back to the more standard `hostname`:

```
echo "Welcome, $(whoami), to $(scutil --get ComputerName 2>/dev/null || hostname)."
```

Comment: The USER environment variable is set by the login process, so it's safe to use `$USER` with any shell.

Answer (score 4):

Many but not all Unix like system's `uname` have the `n` option

```
    uname -n
```

Comment: What (less than 20 year-old) Unix-like system doesn't support it?

Answer (score 0):

Hostnames on GNU/Linux are simply inside a file. For example, I can edit my hostname on Slackware by changing a single line in `/etc/HOSTNAME`.

My suggestion would just be to concatenate that file into your command in bashrc. If your system does not have a hostname file in `/etc` you can simply create one. Also, you can use `$USER` instead of `whoami` because the variable `USER` is populated with the name of whoever is logged in.

This is what the command can look like:

```
echo "Welcome, $USER, to `cat /etc/HOSTNAME`"
```